# UNC path is invalid when starting ASP.NET Core Application in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, iis-10, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a shared drive on my local network \hostname\shared\resource. I have mounted the drive programattically from within the Asp.net core web application in the startup.cs file.

```
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions{
    FileProvider = new 
    PhysicalFileProvider(@"\\TS3410D618\NickFlicks\Movies"),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/Movies"),
    EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false
});
```

This works perfectly when I run it with IIS express(debugging), however, when I deploy it to my local IIS on the same machine the application fails to start with the error:

> Application startup exception: System.ArgumentException: The directory name 
>       \\TS3410D618\NickFlicks\MoviePosters\ is invalid.

This is a valid UNC path and can be reached from everywhere I have tried on my windows 10 machine. As I mentioned everything is on the same machine except for the shared drive.

As a side note I can mount a virtual drive from within IIS sucessfully, so IIS can access the fileshare without any issues.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Learn the differences, and then you should know why https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: @LexLi I understand the differences now but, I still don't know and cannot find, how to change the permissions for an IIS user.

Comment: The common approach is to set a service account (in AD) as application pool identity for your website, and then configure UNC path access permissions so that this service account has at least read permission (if your web app requires more, you need to grant more).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could never get this to work because I couldn't find a way to create an Active Directory with Windows 10 or to modify the user permissions for the UNC file share for the user used by IIS. Basically, I just installed Ubuntu server with Nginx as the reverse proxy and everything worked fine once I set up the permissions properly, which was very straight forward.